# How come a C++ template returns a hexadecimal value?

Tags: c++

I have a simple C++ class that uses generic templates to store and retrieve generic variables. Storing them is no issue but returning the generic variable returns a hexadecimal value.

Could someone tell me why it's doing that?

**node.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Node {
    private:
        T data;
        Node *next_node;

    public:
        Node(T data) {
            this->data = data;
            std::cout << "Node with data - " << this->data << " - has been created." << std::endl;
        }
        
        T get_data() {
            return this->data;
        }
        
        void set_next_node(Node next) {
            this->next_node = next;
        }

        Node get_next_node() {
            return this->next_node;
        }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"

int main() {

    Node node = new Node("Hello World");

    std::cout << "Node data: " << node.get_data() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
gabriel@desktop:/media/gabriel/main/repositories/CPP Sandbox/nodes$ g++ main.cpp -o main
gabriel@desktop:/media/gabriel/main/repositories/CPP Sandbox/nodes$ ./main
Node with data - Hello World - has been created.
Node with data - 0x55ec552d3eb0 - has been created.
Node data: 0x55ec552d3eb0
```

Comment: The code you show, and the output you show, do not match. Your code won't even compile 
 Please provide a [mre]

Comment: what do you think that `T` is ? and very much related to that, why do you use `new`?

Comment: @ChrisMM What do you mean the output doesn't match? I've updated the question.

Comment: you mangaged to get `Node x = new Node` to compile, +1 for that. It is an interesting case of maximum confusion caused by pointless use of `new`.

Comment: The text in it is different from the output. Thus, they cannot be connected.

Comment: @ChrisMM it does compile, there are two different instantations of `Node`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, you're right. Should have read more carefully. Though, output still doesn't match with code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You're right. Removing the new fixed it. When should I use ``new`` when initiating a class? (I'm still learning C++ so please bare with me).

Comment: The OP's first line of code in their `main` is effectively doing this: `Node node{ new Node("Hello World") };`. Thus creating *two* nodes with the named one having it's template type as `Node*`.

Comment: Mmm... I never considered class template argument deduction could have this specific gotcha. C++ and its emerging properties gets "better" every day.

Comment: I don't think the duplciate is appropriate. There is much more going on in this code. And the address is not from printing an array. Vote to reopen

Comment: What do you think the value of `T` is for `node`? `std::string`? `const char[12]`? What you actually have is a `Node<Node<const char*>*>`.

Comment: Wow, this line `Node x = new Node` is ultra confusing, I think it deserves an actual answer.

Comment: "This line" is the result of someone who knows C# or Java attempting to learn C++ and assuming that C++ works the same way. It doesn't.

Comment: the funny thing is that its possible to write another constructor and a deduction guide that makes `Node x = new Node` do the "right thing". Finally it is possible to write this in C++. Whoohooo. I don't think thats what they had in mind when introducing ctad :D

Comment: "when should I use new" - never. (You will now when you have to, but never is a good approximation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) (class template argument deduction) the line in main reads like this:

```
Node<Node<const char*>*> node = new Node<const char*>("Hello World");
```

I am not sure what you actually wanted, but I am certain that it isn't this.

The address that is printed is value of the `Node<const char*>*` member of the `Node<Node<const char*>*>`.

---

Be warned, what follows is bad taste. It is a joke. If you do not get the joke, forget that you have seen the code. Don't do this at home. Or at work. Or really anywhere. Not. In c++. Please. Ok, lets do it.

I removed some cruft from OPs code and also the string literal to avoid possible confusion about conversions or array to pointer decay. Now, this will produce the *expected* output of `42`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node(T data) : data(data) {}
    Node(Node<T>* other) : data(other->data) { delete other; }
};

int main() {
    Node node = new Node(42);
    std::cout << "Node data: " << node.data << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem you are facing is that you are using `new` to create a node but then trying to assign the ***pointer*** returned to a non-pointer `Node` variable.

This line is the problem:

```cpp
Node node = new Node("Hello World");
```

What this does is to first construct an *unnamed* `Node` object with a template type of `const char *`; then, by using the *pointer* to that new object to initialize your `node` variable, you are constructing a second `Node` object, with the deduced template type being `Node*`. The `cout` lines showing hexadecimal values are **correctly** displaying the address value stored in that second, *named* `Node` variable.

You can get round this in several ways. The easiest is to not use the `new` operator:

```cpp
Node node{ "Hello World" }; // Construct object directly
```

Another way would be to continue using the `new` call but then make your `node` a pointer:

```cpp
int main() 
{
    Node<const char*>* node = new Node("Hello World"); // Or auto node = new Node("Hello World");
    std::cout << "Node data: " << node->get_data() << std::endl; // Now we need "->" instead of the "."
    delete node;
    return 0;
}
```

The first line of code in *your* `main` function is, effectively, doing this:

```cpp
Node node{ new Node("Hello World") };
```

Thus creating two nodes with the named one having it's template type as `Node<const char*>*`. Or, to put it another way, your first line is equivalent to the following, with *explicit* template types:

```cpp
Node< Node<const char*>* > node = new Node<const char*>("Hello World");
```

Also note that the `=` operator here is *not* an assignment but an initialization; this is why the constructor is called.